# SQL - Get row at certain %

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to work out if this is possible:

I would like to add all of the values of a row up via `SUM`, so for example:

```
120
6239
2810
123
```

This would be `SUM()` and would equal 9292.

I would then like to run a query that selects the specific row that is equal to a percentage. So say I have 79.612%, I would like to select the row that matches this percentage of the total.

Any idea?

Comment: Which row matches 79.612%?

Comment: Where does the percentage come from,  the sum is equal to 9292 - and the percentage is 79.612 but what is this a percentage off, the total sum or what ?

Comment: I think this should work from what you meant     SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE value = (
    SELECT SUM(value)*percentage/100 FROM table_name
)

Comment: None of the rows from your example would match the % in your example, what happens in this case?

Comment: If you don't provide further details on the issue, we won't be able to help you out. So you calculate the percentage based on what? I mean, Sum() function is only available on the select clause and, if I'm not wrong, what you want to do would be carried out using a SQL script within the database (perhaps a stored procedure).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear. The idea of this is for a provably fair system, so the % is generated before any of the numbers are given. I want to get the value closest to that %, or the row that aligns with that %, if that makes sense?

Comment: @TylerWilson so the percentage is passed in and not retrieved from a table ?

Comment: @Chris correct, it is going to be a random percentage from 0-100 every time, and I need the row that it matches, or closest to if that is possible.

Comment: Please add table structures, sample data, and expected output given that sample data to your questions so that people don't have to guess at what you're trying to do. Also useful would be what you've tried so far and how/why it didn't work. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you mean by "closest"? It's a bit ambiguous for me. Which of provided rows should be returned for given params (9292 as sum and 79,612% as the random param) ?

Comment: @dragoste I don't believe what I am trying to do is possible. Each row in the table would be a value of what a user enters as a value (into a jackpot), before the jackpot is created a % is chosen that will win. I want to get the value that wins from the percentage. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Took a crack at answering your question based off the information provided but as our comments suggest we need more information around where the percentage comes from.

```
Select * from yourTable -- The table you want to match the percentage table
where SomePercentage = select (sum(value) / 
(select sum(value) from yourTable2)) * 100  -- Total value used as upper bracket of percentage
from yourTable2 where someValue like '123' -- Whatever you want to base the percentage off
```

Edit to match updated requirements where the percentage is passed in and we get the value closest? to the figure.

```
Select top 1 * from yourTable where
value <= (Select (Sum(somevalues) * @In_Percentage)/100 from yourTable2) 
order by value desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. Its working fine with SQL Server 2012 .

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Value int)
INSERT INTO @Table
(Value)
VALUES
(120),(6239),(2810),(123)

Select t.Value FROM @Table t
GROUP BY t.[Value]
HAVING (100*t.value)/(Select sum(t.Value) FROM @Table t) >79.612
```

Comment: correct in my opinion, but the grouping in the outer query is unnecessary.